# Why ReactJs says "warning 'counter:' is defined but never used" but variable is used?

Tags: reactjs

This is a piece of a React Component:

```
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
         counter: 0
     };
 }

 handleClick (event) {
     this.setState((prevState, props) => {
         counter: props.counter + 1
     });
     console.log(this.state.counter);
 }
```

Trying to execute this page, browser wite these lines of warning in console:

```
/Volumes/Development/react-hello-world/src/App.js
  17:13  warning  Using 'LabeledStatement' is not allowed                                no-restricted-syntax
  17:13  warning  Unexpected labeled statement                                           no-labels
  17:13  warning  'counter:' is defined but never used                                   no-unused-labels
  17:22  warning  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

✖ 4 problems (0 errors, 4 warnings)
```

I am using the counter here: "console.log(this.state.counter);". Why that error message?

Why if I change

```
 this.setState((prevState, props) => {
     counter: props.counter + 1
 });
```

with

```
 this.setState({
     counter: props.counter + 1
 });
```

it works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

```javascript
counter: props.counter + 1
```

means create [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) named `counter`. However, you indeed never use this label after.

You probably wanted

```javascript
this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: props.counter + 1
}));
```

Note, that you just need to wrap `{}` in arrow function with parenthesis. Otherwise `{}` is considered as function body block and not an object returned from this function function, which you want in your case.

Comment: Is not `console.log(this.state.counter);` using label counter?

Comment: No, label is not the same as variable or property. Check the link to MDN I included in the answer.

Comment: Uh, sorry. You saw a label, but s a variable. I've updated my code. There was a typo on my first copy and paste.

Comment: See updated answer. You just need to wrap `{}` in arrow function with parenthesis. Otherwise `{}` is considered as function body block and not an object returned from function which you want in this case.

Comment: instead of `this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: props.counter + 1
}));` I use `this.setState((prevState, props) => ({
  counter: prevState.counter + 1
}));`